# Sobre Objeto e Extensões

Tags: javascript, objetos

Estou agora a começar em Javascript estou a aprender através de sites. fui a um excelente site (http://tableless.github.io/iniciantes/manual/js/objetos.html) e até agora tudo estava bem. Só que chegando à parte dos (Objectos) o código não dá em nada. A questão é que o código não me parece errado. Acho que eu é que não estou a colocar o código por completo ou então não estou a guardar com a extensão correta. Já pensei em muitas coisas e como já não fala muito em inserir no código no HTML (que é o que tenho feito), talvez seja para usar um programa próprio ou algo.
Peço que me ajudem.

Comment: Olá, bem vindo. Você é iniciante em javascript e html? Qual parte do código você está tentando implementar? Poderia mostrar?

Comment: Todo mundo esbarra nessa questão de objeto em Javascript. E que na verdade o conceito de orientação a objetos na linguagem Javascript se da forma diferente que outras linguagem. Ai onde boa parte de material na net quer entrar nessa abordagem classe que é especificamente do paradigma (Orientado Objeto), e o Javascript não tem classe nativa. Tudo na linguagem é um objeto (Array, Funções, Number...) que por consequência tem seu construtor de objeto, onde você encapsula seus propriedades/métodos. Aconselharia entender a linguagem mais afundo e depois aplicar a programação orientada a objeto!

Answer (score 0):

Bem, vou considerar que você está executando esse código abaixo:

```js
var album = new Object();
album.title = "Metallica (Black Album)";
album.released = 1991;
album.showInfo = function() {
  alert("Título do álbum: " + this.title + "Lançado em: " + this.released);
};
album.showInfo();
```

Execute e veja no alert o resultado.

Esse é um exemplo didático, explicado passo à passo pelo autor. Em certo momento ele diz:

> Como os métodos são funções, você deve adicionar um par de parênteses - () - quando for acessá-los.

Então é só você chamar o método(que é uma função) do seu objeto:

> album.showInfo();